What Keeps the Engine Running When a Manual Car Stops on an Uphill Slope?
I've got a question about driving a manual car uphill. When you're driving uphill and the car stops, you can still hear the engine revving. What mechanism is preventing the pistons from stopping too since the car has stopped moving?
I've noticed a delay between the time the engine shuts off and the car stopping. The car stops first, you hear the engine revving, and then finally, the engine stops. What exactly is happening in those few seconds before a stall?
I know that Automatic Transmission Slip explains this scenario in automatic cars, but how does it work with a manual transmission? How is the engine running while it's connected to the wheels that are stationary? like the wheels and the engine are connected, one is turning the other is not how's that possible.
edit: there should be no delay actually (given that the clutch is not depressed), when the wheels stop the engine should stop instantly, if a delay is observed it can be explained by a slipping clutch.

In the last part of the question, have you stalled the car by stopping with the brake, while it is in gear, and without depressing the clutch?

Uh, perhaps you didn't brake at all, but the car ran out of puff on a steep incline. Perhaps the engine was driven backwards as you rolled down the hill.

To answer your edit to the question, any competent driver of a manual transmission car will have disengaged the clutch before bringing the car to a complete stop, so the engine will never be connected to the wheels by the time the car stops.
When starting to move again, the clutch is released slowly as power is applied, so some slipping is used to start things up without stalling the engine. Note that this is difficult on a hill - this is why you may see a manual transmission car roll backwards a little bit when starting to move on a hill.

Year, make , model? Does this vehicle use auto stop start when braked to a stop? I have a vehicle with auto stop start but its for an automatic xmission. Stating the clutch pedal isn't depressed yet the engine still runs then stops, when stopped suggests a feature from your vehicle not revealed in your questions?

have you ever driven a manual car?

"you're driving uphill and the car stops" — What exactly does that mean? Why did the car stop?

"you hear the engine revving" — That would be an entirely different problem. I think you mean "running", not "revving".

"When a Manual Car Stops on an Uphill Slope?" — What is the significance of the slope being uphill rather than downhill, or level?

@RayButterworth my guess is that the OP is driving up a steep hill in a high gear, and does not know how to drive a manual. The car stalls, and the clutch slips because they have applied full throttle.

Quite simply, the clutch. With the push of the foot on the clutch pedal, the driver detaches the power from the engine to the transmission. When ready to go again, the driver slowly lets the pedal out and the power is reapplied and the car goes again.

It's true, but does it answer the cute question?

There are two points of connection between the engine and the wheels - the clutch (connecting the engine output to the transmission input) and the transmission (connecting the transmission input to the transmission output (and from there to the differential and to the wheels)). Most (all?) transmissions have a neutral setting, where the input and output shafts of the transmission are disconnected.
It doesn't matter if the car is on an incline or not. Once it stops and the wheels are still connected to the engine (with the clutch being engaged and the transmission in gear), the engine will stall. The driver will need to either depress the clutch pedal, shift the transmission to neutral, or both.

On a manual transmission some clutches have some slip.
If stopping a car/truck without pressing in the clutch, there should be some milli-seconds to seconds before the engine will stall, depending on clutch slip(less is better).
Clutches uses fiction to bind the engine to the wheels.  Doing this at high engine RPMs/speed, not at idle, will cause damage that your wallet will not like.
